# Infinite loop on JS for

Tags: reactjs, firebase

My code stays in the second `for` forever, testing the same category every step and decrementing every time.

I have two arrays, one of them is called `categoriesToUpdate` and is a list of category ids (string values) for categories that I have to update, and the other is called `categories`, containing all the actual category data I'm working with.

I have to test if the `id` value for a category that I have to update is the same as the database and if it is, decrement the attribute `position` of its object and update the database. But it is infinitely decrementing the bank.

```
let newCategory;
let name;
let position;
for(let id of categoriesToUpdate) {
    for(let cat of categories) {
        if(id === cat.id) {
            position = cat.category.category.lastPosition - 1;
            name = cat.category.category.categoryName;
            newCategory = {
                category: {
                    categoryName: name,
                    lastPosition: position,
                }
            }
            cRef.child(id).update(newCategory);
        }
    }
}
```

Examples of the two arrays:

```
categoriesToUpdate = ['-lGz4j77...', '-uEbKO3...', ...]
```

and

```
categories = [
  {
    category: {
      category: {
        categoryName: "name",
        lastPosition: "number",
      }
    },
    id: "category id";
  },
  {
    ...
  }
]
```

it is difficult to explain how I get the arrays, but basically, categoriesToUpdate is an array of ids that I add to my logic, I have to do update in each of these categoriesand categories is an array that has all categories of the database, comes from Firebase.

Comment: Where is `categories` coming from? (it's nowhere in the code you show)

Comment: Categories is an array that I mounted by taking the saved data from Firebase.

Comment: No, you don't understand: show where it's coming from and what's in it. It's mystery data in your code example right now. The same for categoriesToUpdate really: take what is in those, and then hardcode them as an [mcve]. Usually, that lets you immediately spot the problem yourself _while writing your question_ but if it doesn't you have self-contained code that others can look at and know what's happening.

Comment: I tried to exemplify how the two arrays are, I edited the publication

Comment: so there is a `category`-keyed object that has itself an object in it keyed on `category` as well?

Comment: yes, https://imgur.com/a/g8a87Ya < 
console.log of the arrays

Comment: Can you rewrite that last paragraph, too? It doesn't matter how you get your arrays, what matters is the role the data plays. Does your code simply get both the `categoriesToUpdate` array and the `categories` array, rather than you forming them from something? If so, there's no need to be secretive about their origin: their origin is irrelevant for the question =) Final question: what is "the bank"? You mention it gets updated, but you never explain what it is, where it comes from, or where you're updating it (nothing in your code suggests a "bank", either as var or as service)

Answer (score 0):

let id of `categoriesToUpdate`. I'm assuming `categoriesToUpdate` is an array of `Category` objects. So id is actually a `Category` object. To compare it should be `id.id === cat.id`.

Also you can try `filter` instead of a second loop.
Something like

`var matched = categories.filter(c => c.id === id.id)[0];`

Then compare matched. Nested loops are hard to read, imo.